# How to parse JSON firebase in React.js

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field widgetJSON of type string in my firebase database, I give it to my React component using Redux. When i try to make it as JSON object using `JSON.parse(this.props.widgetJSON)` in any function, i got the following error :

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.
```

Edit : On firefox i got the error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I'v already try to make a copy of this variable but it doesn't change anything.

How can i colve this ?
Thank you :) !

Comment: What does the string look like?

Comment: '{"result":"YT", "refresh":42}'

Comment: Looks like "YT" is missing the quotes: `'{"result":"YT", "refresh":42}'`

Comment: My bad, the quotes are present

Comment: Then could you share some code? How are you getting the json value? When are you using JSON.parse? Etc

Comment: This is just a theory, since we would need you to share some code or minimal reproducible example in order to actually pinpoint the issue. However, it looks like you don't have the proper CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) settings configured on your back or your front (most probably on your back) so the request ends up in a error message which is not  JSON ergo, can't be parse to one. To confirm this, check the inspector on the "network" tab and click on the request to see what the response actually is.